# Trying to make changes to page (post/article) text just before they are rendered

Tags: views, nodes

I have a module that works fine but I cannot seem to get node_view hook to work - seems to never be called. As a test, I tried adding this to the dennis.module in sites/all/modules/dennis, but nothing happens (Drupal 7).

```
function dennis_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  echo "AAAAAAAAAA";

  $node->content['body'] = array(
    '#markup' => "bonjour!"
  );

  $node->content['body'][0]['#markup']="hello";
}
```

Ultimately I need to find keywords in the content and replace with other text. So easy in WordPress and Joomla but after days of trying I have got nowhere with Drupal. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the code, but could you use the [String Overrides module](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) for this?

> **Features:**
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need a few easy text changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to do this within my own module. It's part of how my module should work, not a one-off thing. I dont want to change the articles' text itself as stored in the database, just modify it on display.

Comment: Sadly, seems impossible to do this basic thing in Drupal so looks like I'll have to drop Drupal from supported CMSs.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by jQuery also :

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace('Original Text','New Text'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to do this server-side.